# Gstreamer Python - plugin works with gst-launch-1.0 but not when the pipeline is created manually

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer

I am using gstreamer v1.14.5 with Python bindings. I have created a plugin by subclassing the `GstBase.BaseTransform` class and overriding its `do_transform_ip` method. The plugin draws a rectangle on the video frame.

```
class MyPlugin(GstBase.BaseTransform):

    def do_transform_ip(self, buffer: Gst.Buffer) -> Gst.FlowReturn:
        logging.info("in do_transform_ip")

        # draw rectangle on the video frame
        # I won't go into the implementation details here

        return Gst.FlowReturn.OK
```

The plugin works well when used with `gst-launch-1.0`:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! myplugin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

I have added debug messages to the `do_transform_ip` and those messages are displayed in the terminal. And rectangle is drawn on the video.

[image]

However when I create the pipeline manually, like in the code below, it seems like the plugin's `do_transform_ip` method is not called.

```
pipeline = Gst.Pipeline.new("test-pipeline")

source = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videotestsrc")
my_plugin = Gst.ElementFactory.make("myplugin")
converter = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert")
sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("autovideosink")

pipeline.add(source)
pipeline.add(my_plugin)
pipeline.add(converter)
pipeline.add(sink)

source.link(my_plugin)
my_plugin.link(converter)
converter.link(sink)

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
```

No log messages are displayed in the terminal and the rectangle is not drawn on the video. The video output of `videotestsrc` is displayed properly, but without the rectangle.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: did you find the solution to this problem? if yes can you pls share it?